# GitHub Wiki pages sort order?

Tags: github, wiki

I don't seem to be able to give a sort order to the Wiki pages of a project on GitHub. Does this option even exist?

[image: GitHub pages screenshot]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It does not.

But you can use the side bar to make a custom 'table of contents' where you can put them in any order you want, with headings and everything, see below (from https://github.com/BrechtDeMan/WebAudioEvaluationTool/wiki)

You may want to have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239588/toc-or-sidebar-in-github-wiki).

[image]

Comment: Going to the wiki linked in this answer and clicking on the small `Edit` tool (the small pen) gives a concrete example of how to write your own file.

Answer (score 19):

Another approach is to prepend numbers in front of your page titles.

```
1. Home
2. Installation
3. Domain
4. CmsMethods
```

Comment: @affhendrawan Then prepend zeroes: `01`, `02`, `03`, etc. But really this is just a quick and dumb approach for simple use cases.

Comment: This is a good solution for simple wiki's, however keep in mind that when you want to add a new page number 2 and rename page 2 to 3, 3 to 4, etc. That the links of you wiki pages change. So all links to these pages break

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [github-wiki-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-wiki-sidebar) npm module to enforce an order of the pages and also generate the sidebar menu.

- install the npm module locally

  ```
  npm install github-wiki-sidebar -g
  ```
- clone your wiki repository

  ```
  git clone <https://github.com/<username>/<my-project-name>.wiki.git
  cd <my-project-name>.wiki
  ```
- execute the **tutorial** action with **--git-push** flag

  ```
  github-wiki-sidebar --action=tutorial --git-push
  ```

Leave the default options for all the queries besides the ordering. Here a list of all your files will be displayed with the option to change the default order. You can check an example below from the module's documentation:

[image]

In the end, your GitHub wiki sidebar is updated as the --git-push command will also commit your changes to *origin* repository. It adds the modified _Sidebar.md file an option.json file to store your options for any following updates.