# How to make Github Wiki Sidebar with Tiers

Tags: github, sidebar, wiki

I'm trying to make it so that my wiki sidebar has tiers or folders for organization, however, the github documentation is horrible and explains nothing. I've been a developer for 12 years and can't figure out their documentation.

I googled it and found another post with a number of answers ([ToC or Sidebar in GitHub Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239588/toc-or-sidebar-in-github-wiki)), but none of them work for me. I can't figure out Gollum to save my life and while popular, people don't seem to think fondly of it. I also found github-wiki-sidebar, but when I try to run the git-push for it, it won't allow me to finish and gets stuck at the request for it, it won't let me past the request for a category separator and won't allow me to just use defaults.

IDK what to do and my OneNote documentation is far too big. Can someone help me? I'm speechless for why this isn't in the wiki by default.